# express-session is not returning cookie when set cookie.secure = true

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, session-cookies

When I set cookie.secure flag to `true` it's NOT returning cookie to client.

Noticed that

1. it's saving the session data at database
2. it's returning cookie if set cookie.secure = false
3. app is returning all remaining secure cookies

```html
var app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
  name: '_usr',
  store: new pgStore({.......})
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'strict' }
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior if you're working locally (HTTP):

> browsers which support the secure flag will only send cookies with the
> secure flag when the request is going to a HTTPS page

https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/SecureFlag

Comment: Hi @t3__rry, the issue is in production which is HTTPS enabled